# usb key is not loading up in 'My Computer', but is present in device manager

Tags: usb, troubleshooting, usb-flash-drive

I have a usb key, it is working fine on my other machine.  However, on this computer, when I plug it in, it recognizes it but will not load up as accessible under 'My Computer' and no autoplay stuff comes up.  What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click My Computer and click manage, open Disk Management and ensure the USB device is assigned a drive letter

Comment: Smooth!  Another network drive was using the same letter.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it empty?

Control Panel > Folder Options > View > uncheck "Hide empty drives in the computer folder" > click OK.

Ah, seems answer has been posted since I started my post.